# Colab: chromedriver is not included in PATH

Tags: python-3.x, path, selenium-chromedriver, google-colaboratory

I tried to practice selenium module on colab, after installing selenium module and unzipped chromedriver_win32.zip.  I type,

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

I got the error messages like my title,

```
Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see 
https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

But I couldn't find any 'PATH' message to deal with this situation. What should I do?

Comment: This is my problem too.

Answer (score -1):

You need to Refer : https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/getting-started

And you locate Path in executable file or Environment Variable

[image]

[image]

Comment: @Raksha Read full answer and then comment. There is python stuff relevant to question. Answer includes full explanation with ref to beginners.

Comment: I also cannot figure out how to get this to work on Colab. I looked at the Python code and tried driver = webdriver.Chrome() but got same error executable needs to be in PATH

Comment: Is it possible that it is not possible to get selenium to work in Colab or Databricks as these are in the cloud and, well, there is no Firefox or Chrome?

Comment: Answer is regarding path to Chrome webdriver. IT does not relate to Colab.

Comment: @GivenX Not related to this post but to your question regarding Colab. Turns out, it does work in Colab. See my example: https://github.com/DataScientistMSBA/WebAutomation/blob/main/Selenium_Template.ipynb